# Socket IO not sending new sql data after client connects

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am creating a real-time app using. Socket IO, Node.js, Express.js, React for frontend, and Microsoft SQL for database. I only want to send data when the database is updated or when a new client is connected. Though when the client first connects, the IO connection fires off sending my data to the new client. But when I make a change to my database. The data never gets sent. My code is below. I feel as though I am close, but I am just missing something that makes the code work. I appreciate any kind of help.

````
const app = express();
const httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(httpServer);
const path = __dirname + '/views/';
let sqlQuery = require('./controllers/sqlController').queryDatabase;
let currentQueryData = {};
let connectedSocketID
let objectMatched = true;

app.use(express.static(path))

app.get('/', function (req,res) {
  res.sendFile(path + "index.html");
});

// Function to emit data only when a change is found.
const sendData = (data, socket) => {
  socket.emit('markerCreation', data); 
}

// compare both objects and return a boolean value.
const compareObjects = (object1, object2) => {
  return JSON.stringify(object1) === JSON.stringify(object2);
}

httpServer.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at ${3001}`);
})

io.on('connection', async socket => {
  // Get new Query Data than compare the object with the currently saved Query data
    let newQueryData = await sqlQuery();
    objectMatched = compareObjects(currentQueryData, newQueryData)

    if(!objectMatched) { // If objects matched is not true take the new data and save it in currentQueryData and send data to client.
      currentQueryData = newQueryData;
      sendData(currentQueryData, socket);
    } else if (connectedSocketID !== socket.id) { // If socket is not already connected saved it in connected sockets and send data to client
      connectedSocketID = socket.id;
      sendData(currentQueryData, socket);
    };

    // Issue: Socket IO will stop sending to connected Client. If a new update happens on the sql database the change isn't passed along to 
    // the client.
});```
````

Comment: rather then compareObjects, emit an event when you insert a new value, you can use all of https://nodejs.org/api/events.html as express is built using it, then just listen for the event inside the socket.io connection then emit to client

Comment: You mean when currentQueryData is changed?

Comment: no, when you call sqlQuery (i.e changed to sqlQueryWithEmit), you shouldn't need to store any data in a var in memory, just emit an event when you insert as the data wouldn't change if you don't insert

Comment: I did a simple test to see if I could get it to work. I am not getting anything going to the console when I run npm start. I did put this in socket.io

`myEmitter.emit('sqlQueryWithEmit', () => {
  console.log('test');
})`

Comment: I was successfully able to get the event emitter running. But this seems like its doing what  I tried stopping in the first place. Constantly sending data to my client causing issues with the map rendering. This I can't even stop with conditional statements.